# Referenced entities in Hibernate are null after parent objects are persisted

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 entity classes like below. After the parent object is persisted,
accessing the foreign key referenced object returns null.The entity classes are as below.

I have an Employee entity class like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {
    private long employeeId;
    private String name;
    private long companyId;
    private Company companyByCompanyId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    public long getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(long employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

 @Basic
@Column(name = "company_id")
public long getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", referencedColumnName = "company_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Company getCompanyByCompanyId() {
        return companyByCompanyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyByCompanyId(Company companyByCompanyId) {
        this.companyByCompanyId = companyByCompanyId;
    }
}
```

and a Company entity class like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class Company {
    private long companyId;
    private String companyName;
    private Collection<Employee> employeesByCompanyId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    public long getCompanyId() {
        return companyId;
    }

    public void setCompanyId(long companyId) {
        this.companyId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "company_name")
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyByCompanyId")
    public Collection<Employee> getEmployeesByCompanyId() {
        return employeesByCompanyId;
    }

    public void setEmployeesByCompanyId(Collection<Employee> employeesByCompanyId) {
        this.employeesByCompanyId = employeesByCompanyId;
    }
}
```

This is the controller method in a controller class

```
    @ApiOperation(value="Create a new employee")
            @ApiResponses({})
            @RequestMapping(value= "/createEmployee",method= RequestMethod.POST)
            public Callable<EmployeeDTO> createEmployee(
                    HttpServletRequest request,

                    @RequestBody @Valid final List<EmployeeDTO> employeeDto) {
               long employeeId = employeeService.createEmployee(employeeDto);
              EmployeeDTO createdEmployee = employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId);
return () -> createdEmployee;
    }
```

This is the method for createEmployee(employeeDto) in the service class

```
@Transactional
public long createEmployee(employeeDto){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(employeeDto.getName());
        employee.setCompanyId(employeeDto.getCompanyId());
        Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return savedEmployee.getEmployeeId();
}
```

This is the getEmployee method in the same service class as above.

```
public EmployeeDTO getEmployee(long employeeId) {

        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmployeeId(employeeId);

       EmployeeDTO employeeDTO = new EmployeeDTO();
       employeeDTO.setEmployeeId(employee.getEmployeeId());
       employeeDTO.setName(employee.getName());
   employeeDTO.setCompanyByCompanyId(employee.getCompanyByCompanyId());
    }
```

employee.getCompanyByCompanyId() -> this is where it throws the Null pointer exception.

The companies table already has the company row that I am associating with employee.

Comment: Is the referenced company already in companies table as well? Also, have you confirmed the company object had an id before the save?

Comment: add the code in your questions where you are initializing the `employee` object before calling `save`

Comment: @MatheusMohr yes the referenced company is already in companies table with an id.

Comment: As CodingFreak mentioned, can you add the code where you initialize the object and assign the company to the employee object? Overall, it's easy to miss the company's id after persisting, due to how transactions work and all that, but nullifying the object as a whole is new to me.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I have included the controller method and the service methods to the question for more clarity.

Comment: Well, I've never used hibernate in such fashion (a field for the id and another field for the object the id maps), but unless some dark magic is going on here, it's working as expected. Even though you set the id, and I get your logic on how you expect it to work, Company object is actually null, so it won't have anything when you simply return the object. Judging by how Lazy-load works in JPA, you should try moving the @ManyToOne annotation to the field instead of the getter method, since this way we guarantee lazy-load works as expected and, hopefully, solve this.

Comment: Moving the @ManyToOne annotation to the field and removing from the getter throws a hibernate exception. Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Company, at table: employees, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(companyByCompanyId)]

Comment: @CodingFreak did you get a chance to see my code? I added the whole snippet